# Concatenate in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-concatenation

I have a table with width and height (both integers). I want to display it as are.
For eg: width = 300 and height = 160.
Area = 300 x 160.
I am using the following query

```
  select cast(concat(width,'x',height) as varchar(20)) from table;
```

or

```
select concat(width,'x',height) from table;
```

but I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR: function concat(character varying, "unknown", character varying) does not exist

Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `||` as per: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

```
SELECT COALESCE(width, '') || 'x' || COALESCE(height, '') FROM your_table;
```

Sample fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f10eb/1/0

Comment: Be careful if any column can be null

Comment: sure thing, edited answer to include null-handling.

Answer (score 4):

`concat()` expects strings, not integers. But you can use an explicit cast, just as the error message suggests

```
select concat(width::text, 'x', height::text)
from ...
```