# Combine separate month and year in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

base_table

```
month year  
5     2021
10    2020
```

I want to combine the "month" and "year" column into a proper date column.

```
month_year  
2021-05-01
2020-10-01
```

This seems to be a duplicate question for this:
[Concatenate in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38495006/concatenate-in-postgresql)

I tried both:

```
to_date(CONCAT(year::text, '/'::text, month::text), 'YYYY/MM') as month_year
```

and

```
to_date(CONCAT(year, '/', month), 'YYYY/MM') as month_year
```

but maybe the solution does not work in Redshift.

Comment: Invalid operation: function concat(character varying, character varying, character varying) does not exist;

Comment: make_date seems to be not available for PostGreSQL 8.0 (Redshift)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
(year::text || '-' || month::text || '-01')::date
```

This will use ISO format (`2021-11-19`) for the date.